# Drop a Constraint doesn’t work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting following error when deleting a column with constraint in `SQL Server 2005`.

> The object 'DF__PlantRecon__Test' is dependent on column 'Test'.

The column is not part of any key. But it has a `default` constraint and the constraint has a pre-defined name.

Though I have written code to delete constraint first, it is not working.

1. Why doesn't it work?
2. What need to be done to make it working?

Note: I need to check whether the constraint exist first.

**REFERENCES**

1. [Named CONSTRAINT benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897913/named-constraint-benefits)
2. [How to drop column with constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641954/how-to-drop-column-with-constraint)
3. [How to drop SQL default constraint without knowing its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430456/how-to-drop-sql-default-constraint-without-knowing-its-name?rq=1)

**CODE**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('DF__PlantRecon__Test', 'C') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    SELECT 'EXIST'
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlantReconciliationOptions] drop constraint DF__PlantRecon__Test
END

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME ='DF__PlantRecon__Test')
BEGIN

    SELECT 'EXIST'
    --drop  constraint
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlantReconciliationOptions] drop constraint DF__PlantRecon__Test
END

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM   sys.columns WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[PlantReconciliationOptions]') AND name = 'Test')
BEGIN
    --drop column
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlantReconciliationOptions] DROP COLUMN Test
END

ALTER TABLE PlantReconciliationOptions
ADD Test INT NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT DF__PlantRecon__Test  DEFAULT 30
```

Comment: (Why is the constraint check/drop done twice?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
IF OBJECT_ID('DF__PlantRecon__Test') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    SELECT 'EXIST'
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PlantReconciliationOptions] drop constraint DF__PlantRecon__Test
END
```

In your example, you were looking for a 'C' Check Constraint, which the DEFAULT was not.  You could have changed the 'C' for a 'D' or omit the parameter all together.

If you are consistent with your naming, as it appears you are, (e.g. DF__xxx) then dropping the second parameter is an acceptable choice to be sure that the hard coded constraint name is dropped.

Here is a list of the OBJECT_ID() Object Types you can pass:

```
AF = Aggregate function (CLR)
C = CHECK constraint
D = DEFAULT (constraint or stand-alone)
F = FOREIGN KEY constraint
PK = PRIMARY KEY constraint
P = SQL stored procedure
PC = Assembly (CLR) stored procedure
FN = SQL scalar function
FS = Assembly (CLR) scalar function
FT = Assembly (CLR) table-valued function
R = Rule (old-style, stand-alone)
RF = Replication-filter-procedure
S = System base table
SN = Synonym
SQ = Service queue
TA = Assembly (CLR) DML trigger
TR = SQL DML trigger
IF = SQL inline table-valued function
TF = SQL table-valued-function
U = Table (user-defined)
UQ = UNIQUE constraint
V = View
X = Extended stored procedure
IT = Internal table
```

(This list was found on [Beyond Relational: Using TSQL Function: OBJECT_ID()](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10487/using-tsql-function-objectid.aspx))

Comment: the command OBJECT_ID('DF__PlantRecon__Test') will return a value where OBJECT_ID('DF__PlantRecon__Test', 'C') will not.  Therefore the default constraint WILL be deleted in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to solve your problem.

1. Open SSMS.
2. Edit the table to remove the default. **Do not press save**
3. Script the output to "new window".
4. Read the script.

Comment: That won't help. I need to check whether it exist first.