# What's the reason / usefulness is to use ENABLE keyword in oracle database statements

Tags: sql, database, oracle, keyword

I would like to know what's the advantage or usefulness of using ENABLE  keyword, in statements like:

```
CREATE TABLE "EVALUATION" (
    "EVALUATION_ID" NUMBER(20, 0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE "EVALUATION"
ADD CONSTRAINT("EVALUATION_FK")
FOREIGN KEY ("CREW_ID")
REFERENCES "CREW" ("CREW_ID") ENABLE;
```

For what I read in the documentation, `ENABLE` is on by default.

Could I assume it is just to enable something that has been previously disabled?

Comment: it's not necessary, you can leave it out, as constraints are enabled by default

Comment: this provable is reversed DDL from database metadata.

Comment: The utility lies in clarity: it's just more obvious that the constraint is enabled on creation, without expecting the reader to know that's the default.  On the other hand, it is a bit lazy as it doesn't specify VALIDATE.  Or NOT DEFERRED.  :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**[`Constraint doc`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#i1002273):**

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE "EVALUATION" (
    "EVALUATION_ID" NUMBER(20, 0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
```

**`ENABLE/DISABLE`** indicates that constraint is on or off. By default `ENABLE` is used.

> **ENABLE Clause** Specify ENABLE if you want the constraint to be applied
>   to the data in the table.
>
> **DISABLE Clause** Specify DISABLE to disable the integrity constraint.
>   Disabled integrity constraints appear in the data dictionary along
>   with enabled constraints. If you do not specify this clause when
>   creating a constraint, Oracle automatically enables the constraint.

Constraints are used to ensure data integrity, but there are scenarios we may need to disable them.

**[`Managing Integrity`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general005.htm)**:

> Disabling Constraints
>
> To enforce the rules defined by integrity constraints, the constraints
>   should always be enabled. However, consider temporarily disabling the
>   integrity constraints of a table for the following performance
>   reasons:
>
> - When loading large amounts of data into a table
> - When performing batch operations that make massive changes to a table (for example, changing every employee's number by adding 1000 to
>     the existing number)
> - When importing or exporting one table at a time
>
> In all three cases, temporarily disabling integrity constraints can
>   improve the performance of the operation, especially in data warehouse
>   configurations.
>
> It is possible to enter data that violates a constraint while that
>   constraint is disabled. Thus, you should always enable the constraint
>   after completing any of the operations listed in the preceding bullet
>   list.
>
> **Efficient Use of Integrity Constraints: A Procedure**
>
> Using integrity constraint states in the following order can ensure
>   the best benefits:
>
> 1. Disable state.
> 2. Perform the operation (load, export, import).
> 3. Enable novalidate state.
>
>    Some benefits of using constraints in this order are:
>
>    - No locks are held.
>    - All constraints can go to enable state concurrently.
>    - Constraint enabling is done in parallel.
>    - Concurrent activity on table is permitted.

**EDIT:**

The question is rather why to use **obvious** keyword when it is turn on by default:

I would say:

1. For clarity (Python EIBTI rule **Explicit Is Better Than Implicit**)
2. For completness
3. Personal taste and/or coding convention

This is the same category as:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(col INT NULL)
```

Why do we use `NULL` if column is nullable by default.