# When creating a table does it make sense to have column default to 0 and make it null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking over an old employees SQL code and understand it. Why would they set a new column defaulting to 0 but making it null. Or in this case why even bother placing NULL. If you don't add it won't it already accept NULL?

```
CREATE TABLE Inventory(

Amount INT DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,   --why not just write DEFAULT(0) with no null?
Type   INT DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33219284/5070879

Comment: This is off-topic since it is primarily an opinion-based question. Does it make sense? Depends on your perspective. And the evolution of a schema over time often is a factor. As posted, your table makes little sense IMO - with or without defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, when there is a default of `0`, the column is `NOT NULL`.

But, this allows the column to be set to `NULL` *later* in the processing.  There may be some cases where this is useful.  For instance, if the row represents an item and the column is the count of items involved in something.  Then `0` might mean that there are no items.  And `NULL` might mean that the item is (softly) deleted.

The above is just for a thought exercise.  Personally, I would have a separate flag for soft deletion.

Comment: `NULL` might also mean "In don't know the amount now and will enter the correct value as soon as I know". Where as `0` means: "The value is effectivley `0`".

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes . . . That is possible, but I would expect the value to start at `NULL` in that case.

Comment: It depends how often it happens. If the inventory has a lot of amortized items, `0` might be very common.