# SQL Constraint names

Tags: sql

If we have query for creating table like this..

```
create table if not exists food
(
     id int not null auto_increment,
     user_id int,
     name varchar(30),

     constraint pk_food primary key(id,name),
     foreign key(user_id) references userss(id)
);
```

What does `pk_food` mean in this example? I know this is a constraint name, but for what we should be give a name for constraint, if its working without?

```
create table if not exists food
(
     id int not null auto_increment,
     user_id int,
     name varchar(30),

     primary key (id, name),
     foreign key (user_id) references userss(id)
);
```

I mean.. how to use these names and for what we need it?

Comment: Related [Named CONSTRAINT benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897913/named-constraint-benefits)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You gives constraints names for basically two reasons:

- You can better understand the error message when the constraint is violated.
- You can more easily find the constraint if you want to delete it.

Comment: thank you! because i not found any information in doc